# How to do ping in embed

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

const Discord = require('discord.js')

const client = new Discord.Client()

client.on('ready', () => {

console.log('client');
});

client.on('message', (msg, bot) =>{

if (msg.author.bot) return;

if (msg.content == 'some com') {

msg.delete();

let gifs = [

"some url",

"some url"
];

let pick = gifs[Math.floor(Math.random() * gifs.length)];

```
let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
embed.setImage(pick);
embed.setTitle(`${msg.author.username} ***some msg***`)
.setColor('#2F3136')
msg.channel.send(embed)
}
```

})
client.login('token');

i use this code

Answer (score 0):

You can mention a user in an embed. For eg:-

```
let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setDescription(`${message.authour} this is an example`);
message.channel.send(embed);
```

But unfortunately, it doesn't ping them. So if you want to ping them, you can use:

```
let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setDescription(`This is an example`);
message.channel.send(`${message.authour}`,{embed:embed});
```

where the mention will be outside the embed.

Answer (score 0):

so where do i put it if i have it like this

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")

module.exports = (client) => {
    const welcomechannelId = '918552619729969177' //Channel You Want to Send The Welcome Message
    const targetChannelId = `918562811242758224` //Channel For Rules

    client.on('guildMemberAdd', (member) => {
        console.log(member) // If You Want The User Info in Console Who Joined Server Then You Can Add This Line. // Optional
        const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.get(welcomechannelId)

        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`Welcome To ${member.guild.name}`)
        .setThumbnail(member.user.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true, size: 512}))
        .setDescription(`Hello <@${member.user.id}>, Welcome to **${member.guild.name}**. Thanks For Joining Our Server.
Please Read ${member.guild.channels.cache.get(targetChannelId).toString()}. Have a Nice Time.
Chat In <#918839454549033001>`)

        // You Can Add More Fields If You Want
        .setFooter(`Welcome ${member.user.username}#${member.user.discriminator}`,member.user.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true, size: 512}))
        .setColor('RANDOM')
    channel.send(embed)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. 
Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please edit your question and explain 
how it answers the specific question being asked.